# Please help me understand suspicious transactions moving funds from my wallet

Tags: transactions, wallets

I see some mysterious ETH withdrawals from my address. Could you please help me to understand why it happened?

I have an address [0xee5119...](https://etherscan.io/address/0xee5119eef4f7f03633cd57461952cc07cea869cb) in my local Ethereum wallet. There are transactions [0xf86327...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf86327c88683baf6c539b4d64ab6f7d98af3ae9da0e4acc430252eba1fbb05ee) and [0xa668e5...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa668e5476a5f06da7c36fa60ec70b6112cd67163bbb8d2fbe1aaeb5576b989d5) that move some funds to the address [0x8f0d1d...](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8f0d1d4874e5ab401f87f188f0cb55f914caaaf9).

I do not recognize neither this address nor these transactions. Soon after that, funds are further moved to the address [0xc96d5d...](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc96d5d4d54bd18ea9efcc586c4ec82b7c46c6f6b), which has the current balance of 64063 ETH and a lot of activity.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Is it likely to be malware?

Comment: Ethereum security announcement - https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/24/security-alert-smart-contract-wallets-created-in-frontier-are-vulnerable-to-phishing-attacks/

Comment: AFAI understood yours is not wallet contract but a plain EOA, there is no security issue with externaly owned addresses, or we would be ALL in trouble @AlexDarby

Comment: I think we need more information on this question please. What OS are you using? What wallet software? What were you trying to do?

Comment: @ RolandKofler Yes I know that but I thought the question poster might of been using a contract account from a old version of the wallet software.

Comment: I'll put this on hold as it is most likely impossible to answer this by now. If you have more details, feel free to update the question and reopen it.